# Angular 6 Reload page on parameter change

Tags: routes, angular6, angular-routing

I am using angular 6 to build an app. However I have got a page with list of events  with each event having link to its detail page as `'/events/view/1'`.

I am providing link to my a tag as `<a [routerLink]="['/events/view/', d.EventId]">View Detail</a>`

However, when I click on any event to view its detail, I get the EventId updated in the URL. But the contents in the page are not updated until I manually refresh the page.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in your app-component html? What are the console errors if any?

Comment: Yes, I do have router outlet. However, i got it resolved. The problem was <h1>{{ dealinfo.OfferTitle }}</h1> was replaced by <h1 [innerHTML]="dealinfo.OfferTitle"></h1>

Comment: try `<h1>{{dealinfo?.offerTitle}}</h1>` instead.